# How can I make the rest of my JavaScript Program wait on my jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple application where a user clicks on an area, and the counter moves a number of steps. I am using an console-like output window to alert the user of any changes. For moving the counter, I am using a `for` loop to run the jQuery animations like so:

```
function glideMove() {
    //for length of moveNum, animate square step
    for (var i=1; i <= moveNum; i++) {
        $("#thingToAnimate").animate();
    }// end for loop
    //set squareOn to moveNum
    squareOn += moveNum;
}// end glideMove
```

I call this function from a different number of places in the code, like here:

```
function moveCounter() {
    $("#thingToAnimate").append("Moving...  ").scrollTop(BIG_NUMBER);
    //if square will be last, finish game
    if (squareOn + moveNum>= END_SQUARE) {
        finishThis();
    } else {
        glideMove();
        $("#thingToAnimate").append("you are now on square: " + squareOn + ".<\/br >").scrollTop(BIG_NUMBER);//not
        //roll again
        $("#thingToAnimate").append("Roll again. <br \/>").scrollTop(BIG_NUMBER);
    }// end else if
}// end moveCounter
```

What I want is an alert to the output that the moving animation has begun. Once it has ended, I want an alert to the output that it has finished moving an is ready to continue.

But my problem is, all the alerts to the output run while the animation is still taking place.

What I would like is for the sequence of jQuery animations to run, and have the rest of the program wait on that sequence to complete. This function is called from a number of different places in the code, with different results after the function is complete

Comment: I'm curious to see the answer, too (not knowing much about JS animation), but from a usability perspective I would consider the option of allowing other activity to stop the animation (move it directly to its final state) instead. It doesn't take long for people to tire of the novelty of animations and wish they could just move along.

Comment: You can pass a function to glideMove() that it can execute after the loop.

Comment: @GregPettit Your probably right, and I might work on what you suggested later, but as this is just a simple learning project I think I'll keep it just to this for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should subscribe to the `complete` event for your `animate()` call.

```
function glideMove(callback) {
    //for length of moveNum, animate square step
    for (var i=1; i <= moveNum; i++) {
        //----- New Code -----
        var options = {};
        if (i === moveNum)
            options.complete = callback;
        $("#thingToAnimate").animate({}, options);
        //----- New Code -----
    }// end for loop
    //set squareOn to moveNum
    squareOn += moveNum;
}// end glideMove
```

And now use the `glideMove` function where required with your own on demand function when animation completes

```
function moveCounter() {
    $("#thingToAnimate").append("Moving...  ").scrollTop(BIG_NUMBER);
    //if square will be last, finish game
    if (squareOn + moveNum>= END_SQUARE) {
        finishThis();
    } else {
        glideMove(function() {
            //specific code on this specific 'glideMove' animation
        });
        $("#thingToAnimate").append("you are now on square: " + squareOn + ".<\/br >").scrollTop(BIG_NUMBER);//not
        //roll again
        $("#thingToAnimate").append("Roll again. <br \/>").scrollTop(BIG_NUMBER);
    }// end else if
}// end moveCounter
```

Comment: I don't think i will be able to use this, because, like my question says above, this function will be called from different places, with different events following it.

Comment: OK! then you might consider passing a `callback` function to `glideMove`! I am updating the code. Please check in a moment!

Comment: This updated answer is nice, but I need the rest of the code to run after the _sequence_ of animations has occurred, so after the `for` loop of animations has finished. I have edited my question to reflect that. Sorry if I did not make that clear.

Comment: So you mean to say that you a queue of animation and you want to get notified after the processing of queue is finished?

Comment: Yes, in the `glideMove` function, there is a `for` loop that will iterate a number of times, and i want the alerts to happen once all those animations are complete.

Comment: You can just add a condition on your upper bound of your loop. I am going to update the code of `glideMove`. Check back in few mins!

Comment: Sorry, I have limited internet access at times. Yes this works, thanks for your help. I have not had too much experience with anonymous functions yet so this really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#id').animate({
    //Parameters
      }, duration, function() {
        // Animation complete.
       //show your completion alert here
      });
```